# NullPointerException URLImageSource.getConnection(URLImageSource

Tags: java, image, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception

i'm programming a project in IntelliJ IDEA on my Mac OSX. Everything works just fine when i run the code or when i export the jar and run it. But when i switch to windows, i get an error saying this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(URLImageSource.java:116)
at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(URLImageSource.java:126)
at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:263)
at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:205)
at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:169)
```

I really cannot imagine, what causes that error, cause all ressources are stored in the "res" folder, which is marked as a resource folder (Also some other images are loaded successfully).
The error happens in the last of this code snippet:

```
System.out.println("Starting new Frame");
Variables.theFrame = new JFrame("AudioTaggerUI");
Variables.theFrame.setContentPane(new AudioTaggerUI().getContentPane());
Variables.theFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Variables.theFrame.pack();
```

I hope anyone of you can help me ^^

Comment: None of those method calls are in your stack trace, but if I had to guess, I'd say the image resource it's trying to load doesn't exist in the path you specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there are any hardcoded path names (with file separators)

Comment: well there are hardcoded paths. e.g.: `private ImageIcon iIButtonUp = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Buttons/Button_Up.png"));`

But if there would be an error, it would show it in this line, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i solved the Problem by myself. This line threw (indirectly) the Error:

```
Variables.theFrame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/gui/icon.png")));
```

I changed the line to this one:

```
Variables.theFrame.setIconImage(getToolkit().getImage(Image.class.getResource("/gui/icon.png")));
```

Thanks @ all for your help